# Filtering users by business phone number with MS Graph API fails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

According to the [MS Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0), **businessPhones** are supported to be used in a **$filter** query with **eq** comparison, just like the **imAddresses** property.
[image]

When inspecting Microsoft's [use query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) documentation, there's an example where the **imAddresses** property is used in a collection filter and it works just fine.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=imAddresses/any(s:s eq 'admin@contoso.com')`

My goal ist to list all users that have a specific phone number in their **businessPhones** collection property.
However, when I try to use the **businessPhones** property in a similar query, the query does not work as expected.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=businessPhones/any(s:s eq '1234')`

Status code: 400

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'businessPhones' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-07-30T08:07:24",
            "request-id": "ac3923be-de11-448f-b2b5-245edc82d20e",
            "client-request-id": "ac3923be-de11-448f-b2b5-245edc82d20e"
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: From the error message it seems like this field is not supported and the documentation is not clear on that. Let me follow up.

Comment: Any news on this, I too am running into problems trying to filter on businessPhones.

Comment: @MHugh the accepted answer solved my issues, did you try it? If you not, I would suggest opening a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [advanced query capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries), which means you need to add a `$count=true` query string parameter and a `ConsistencyLevel=Eventual` header to your request.

[image]